# ASP.NET Login Control reset failuretext

Tags: asp.net, login-control

I have a login control in an asp.net page. On MSDN it is specified that the FailureText property, if not specified, defaults to 
"Your login attempt has failed. Please try again."

I needed to enter a custom message on failed login on the Login1_LoggingIn event, so that when the password is entered 4 times incorrectly , the account is locked and I notify the user on this event.

However, after the lock time expires, I need to revert to the default "Your login attempt has failed. Please try again" msg. is there any way to revert the FailureText property to its default state?

The problem is that if I overwrite the FailureText on the above mentioned event, it stays that way for all subsequent postbacks.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just hook into the Login1_LoginError event and change the message from there, you can then decide what to display each time a failure occurs i.e

```
private void Login1_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    failureCount++; //Retrieve this from Database or something

    if (failureCount >= 4)
    {
        Login1.FailureText = "Account is locked";
    }
    else
    {
        Login1.FailureText = "Your login attempt has failed. Please try again";
    }
}
```